# Redirect standart stream (Process.Start)

Tags: c#, process

I have the following code:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process process = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

        processStartInfo.Arguments = "-i 1 -x";
        processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        processStartInfo.FileName = @"F:\NET\WiresharkPortable\App\Wireshark\tshark.exe";
        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
        process.Start();

        StreamReader streamReader = process.StandardOutput;
        textBox1.AppendText(streamReader.ReadToEnd() + "\r\n");
    }
```

I'm trying to redirect the output to my program. tshark is sniffer, so it works until was suspended. How to redirect data in real time? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently calling `ReadToEnd`, which will block to the end of the stream.

You could *either* repeatedly call `Read` from a separate thread, *or* you could use the newer eventing approach, handling [`Process.OutputDataReceived`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived.aspx) for each line after calling [`BeginOutputReadLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline.aspx). Don't forget to marshal back to the UI thread before changing the textbox.